# BLE devices are not being scanned by my android application

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have made a simple android application to scan the neighbouring BLE enabled android devices and display their device address and names on the application. The application seems to be running fine but the BLE devices are not being scanned.The BLE devices which i used are MOTO G and HTC ONE E8 .Kindly give an appropriate solution. I have provided the callback methods implementation below.

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = 
                         new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: I have referred the following link in making my application.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18548987/DeviceScanActivity.rar

Comment: can anyone please give a quick solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

Long shot but, have you added the following to your `mainfest.xml`?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

To check if your device supports BLE, you can add the following:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

> However, if you want to make your app available to devices that don't support BLE, you should still include this element in your app's manifest, but set required="false". Then at run-time you can determine BLE availability by using PackageManager.hasSystemFeature():

Have a look over the android docs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107971/ble-devices-are-not-being-scanned-by-my-android-application).

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested but still its not working out.Can u suggest a solution by going through the code?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't currently have any BLE devices but if you've followed the developer documentation in my post you should be seeing your devices populated.

Answer (score 0):

Android only supports central role, and central cannot be discovered by another central.